# Javascript script loading multiple times

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a webpage with a link on it.  You click on the link, and it generates a table inside of a `<div>` with AJAX.  Along with the table, when this `<div>` loads it calls some javascript into play so that the user can up/down vote on items in the table.  My problem is, if the user clicks that same link to regenerate the `<div>`, it reloads a SECOND javascript, so that clicking the upvote arrow once actually runs +1 twice.  I don't know if you'll need to see any specific code, or if there is some general way to fix this, but here is a clearer picture of my file setup.

**mainpage.php** with link called "show table"

**voting.js**

**getTable.php**

*Click on "show table" on main page, **getTable.php** is called.

***getTable.php** calls **voting.js** so that user can vote on items

*Click "show table" again and ANOTHER **voting.js** is called

*Now clicking upvote arrow passes through twice the +1 code.

What can a guy do?

Comment: A guy can post some `//example code` for one...

Comment: By 'getTable.php calls voting.js' do you mean it inserts the contents of that file into the page? Or does it include the file via a script tag?

Comment: @pixelbobby I can include code, but not sure what specifically you want to see.  I don't want to put up 3 pages of code if you don't need it.

Comment: @jayp voting.js is called with a script file on getTable.php

Comment: you should provide more clearer concept so that we can help you more accurately.

Comment: I am sorry, but can you tell me what more you want?  How would showing all my code help.  This is a conceptual problem and specific pieces of code I believe would be unnecessary.  Am I wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could include the voting.js on mainpage.php instead of getTable.php.  It would be loaded once, but getTable could still use it.

Comment: I believe that worked :). For some reason I thought I tried this and it didn't work, but now its working. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing (guessing, because we don't have the code) that you are appending the data to the div. so instead of appending it, just write/overwrite it.

Answer (score 0):

the way you explained it is a little confusing to me so I am going to base my response on what I think you are having an issue with.

When the user submits the +1 vote it submits it 2 times

you can use a switch, basiclly when they click call an if your switch is on do it, if its not on set it to on and run the code

```
    if(sitchMe == "on"){
        //dont run the code
    }
    else{
        //run it
        switch = "on"
    }
```